# Efficient proximity queries for 2-dimensional geometric data

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of data points D in 2-dimensional space. I have a query point P (in 2-d space). I am looking for an efficient (better than linear time) algorithm that can answer the query : find me the data point d in D that has the closest geometric distance to P.

Any pointers on how to do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an implementation of k-d tree in scipy that does what I want. Note: The K-d tree does not give you worst case O(log(n)) performance but it does give you average case O(log(n)) performance. See:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach based on a [K-D Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: Yes I thought of a quad tree in fact but the issue is that my nearest neighbor may be in the bucket adjacent to the bucket I land in. In fact if I order the points using a morton key, I can get a petty good approximate match this way but sometimes I am off.